# Setting a JSON object into backbone Model

Tags: json, backbone.js

Dumb question I know, but for some reason I keep getting caught up on this.

Most of my values from my backbone model are coming from the database and are JSON. However I have one that I have to set in my code and is tripping me up. I have tried multiple different ways, but nothing I do seems to be readable by `JSON.parse` either it comes back as {object}{object} or a big fat error.

```
this.model.set('CustomProperties', {NAME: "some value", SecondName: null})
```

This comes back with a syntax Error

```
this.model.set('CustomProperties', {"NAME": 'Some Val', "SecondName": null})
```

This comes back as "[object Object]"

Help is needed so my brain does not explode.

Comment: Both examples work as intended http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dwrkagw5/ and set an object as  `CustomProperties` Where would `JSON.parse` play a role?

Comment: Both of them are setting it, but when you read it back out in the JSON.parse that's where I'm getting the error

Comment: So, in your console.log it would be JSON.parse(m1...)

Comment: You mean you're trying to do `JSON.parse(this.model.toJSON())` ?

Comment: I do not have the toJSON in there. I am setting it in one page and trying to pull it out in another

Comment: @nikoshr Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dwrkagw5/1/ I need to be able to pull it out with a JSON.parse. Because this is the only place I'm setting something I have to do it the way the database is everywhere else.